# how to send and receive file by flask and axios

Tags: python, node.js, flask

In the node js, I send a post request, and hope to receive a file from the python flask server. What it sends is not relavent, and I just would like to receive the a jpeg file from the flask server:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const axios = require('axios');

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

function send_test(test_name,...args) {
    const apiurl = `${BASE_URL}/send`;
    
    
    const form = new URLSearchParams();
    form.append('filename', test_name);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    };
    axios.request({
        url: apiurl,
        method: 'POST',
        headers:config,
        data: form,
    
    })
        .then(function (response) {
        
            
            console.log(response.data);
            fs.writeFileSync('result.jpeg', 
            response.data);
        
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        
  });

}
result = send_test('test_name');
```

The flask server returns a jpeg, and it does not matter what it receives from the node js, it does not check the form and just sends a jpeg file:

```
from flask import Flask, request,send_file
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send():
    print('send')

    extracted_name = 'test.jpeg'
   
        
    return send_file(extracted_name, mimetype="image/jpeg")
```

However, when I save file to 'result.jpeg', the file cannot be opened. I think the encoding of the file is important here. How to save the file by fs.writeFileSync()? The first a few bytes of response.data is like :

����JFIFHH��xExifII*1>i�FPicasa�0220��
���C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see from your question why you want to use a post request. In my opinion, a get request is sufficient to download a file.
In the example below, a file is downloaded and saved with a get request. A [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) is used to select the file name. The file is obtained and saved as a stream.

```
function downloadFile(src, dst) {
  axios
    .get(src, { responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(async resp => {
      resp.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst));
    });
}

downloadFile(
  'http://localhost:5000/download/test.jpeg',
  'result.jpeg'
);
```

```
@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, filename)
```

If you still want to send form data to the server, you can slightly modify the example to achieve your goal.

```
function downloadFile(src, dst) {
  const url = 'http://localhost:5000/send';
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('filename', src);
  axios
    .post(url, formData, { headers: formData.getHeaders(), responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(async resp => {
      resp.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst));
    });
}

downloadFile(
  'test.jpeg',
  'result.jpeg'
);
```

If you want to upload a file with axios, I recommend the following procedure.

```
const url = 'http://localhost:5000/upload';
const filePath = path.resolve('result.jpeg');
fs.readFile(filePath, async (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', data, { filepath: filePath, contentType: 'image/jpg' });
  axios
    .post(url, formData, { headers: formData.getHeaders() })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
    });
});
```

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('file');
    # Process the file here.
    return '', 200
```

---

There are several ways to send a file and JSON data in one.

###### Send JSON data in HTTP header:

```
from flask import send_file
import json

@app.route('/send')
def send_json_binary():
    filename = 'test.jpeg'
    resp = send_file(filename, mimetype='image/jpeg')
    resp.headers['X-Metadata'] = json.dumps({
        'filemeta': 'Your metadata here.'
    })
    return resp
```

```
function downloadFile(src, dst) {
  axios
    .get(src, { responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(async resp => {
      const meta = JSON.parse(resp.headers['x-metadata'])
      const filemeta = meta.filemeta;
      resp.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst));
    });
}

downloadFile(
  'http://localhost:5000/send',
  'result.jpeg'
);
```

###### Sending Base64 encoded data within JSON:

```
from flask import jsonify
from base64 import b64encode

@app.route('/sample')
def send_json_binary():
    filename = 'test.jpeg'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        return jsonify(
            filemeta = 'Your metadata here.',
            filedata = b64encode(fh.read()).decode()
        )
```

```
function downloadFile(src, dst) {
  axios
    .get(src, { responseType: 'json' })
    .then(async resp => {
      const meta = resp.data.filemeta;
      const buffer = Buffer.from(resp.data.filedata, 'base64');
      const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dst))
    });
}

downloadFile(
  'http://localhost:5000/send',
  'result.jpeg'
);
```

It depends on your requirements which way you go.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I tried that and resp.data is of type string without the pipe attribute. Any idea?

Comment: The flask side use send_file(extracted_name, mimetype="image/jpeg") to send the file and the axios reponse.data is of type string

Comment: Did you set the `responseType` to `stream` in the axios request? I had this error once when I set the wrong type.

Comment: If you use electron, then you should make the call in the main process. The responseType stream is not available in the browser, so it doesn't work in the renderer process either.

Comment: Thank you Detlef! I forgot to set the responseType before and now it works! One more question: In the flask function, I use return send_file(extracted_name, mimetype="image/jpeg"). How to send back a file with a json form together in flask and the axios then parse that received file and json data?

Comment: @RuiGuo Actually, you should formulate a separate question for this. That goes beyond your previous question. Still, I've exceptionally expanded my answer in this regard. It would be nice if you would click the ✔.